# Changing URL in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I want to change my sharepoint main page URL to a new one.

Now this is something like http://servername/SitePages/Home.aspx but I want to change the server name to a better name like :

http://OurSharePoint.com

how can I do this?

Comment: Hello. Try http://serverfault.com , it is probably better suited for your question. Either way, try adding some details - do you want the site to be online, or on the intranet? What happens when you browse `http://servername`?

Comment: I asked it, you can follow it from http://serverfault.com/questions/182597/changing-sharepoint-2010-url

Comment: Next time please ask for a moderator to migrate your question, please don't crosspost. @Kobi - please just flag for migration, don't encourage new users to crosspost.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Change the alternate access mapping in central administration.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want to do. If you want the site to respond to a certain adress, add a AAM. If you want to rename the server/machine, use:

> Stsadm.exe -o renameserver -oldservername  -newservername

Answer (score -2):

Just creare a root sitecollection in central admin (and delete the Sitepages sitecollection).
Select the "/" option in stead of /sites

Comment: This is such a stupid answer. Why?